# While scrolling page, input fields are get overlapping in windows phone8

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, iscroll

I have a J-query mobile 1.4 Application and i use the I-Scroll 5 plugging.

However, while scrolling on Windows 8 mobile the input and select elements start overlapping.

On other Mobiles I have tested the App with, like Android ,I-Phone and Blackberry 10 don't seem to have this issue.

Can you Please let me know if Win-8 for Mobile has any issues with I-Scroll together with JQM 1.4.

[image]

This image below is taken from Android.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from the other devices so we can compare?

Comment: remove the i-scroll plugging from your page, and see if the problem is with that plugging. It could be that your page has CSS issues so you will need to post some code too

Comment: Hi Tasos,I have removed Iscroll plugging even get same issue.

Comment: Hi Chubosaurus, I have added android mobile screenshot for your reference.